# NivoSlider isn't working with base64 images loaded by AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, nivo-slider

When I use the nivoSlider with static images, it works like a charm:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="img/someimage.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to load the gallery image with some dynamically base64 image (thru AngularJS), it isn't work:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img data-ng-repeat="file in files" src="{{file.content}}" alt="" />
        <!-- or -->
        <img data-ng-repeat="file in files" data-ng-src="{{file.content}}" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the `data-ng-repeat` in a separated content is working

```
<img data-ng-repeat="file in files" data-ng-src="{{file.content}}" alt="" /> 
<!-- or -->
<img data-ng-repeat="file in files" data-ng-src="{{file.content}}" alt="" />
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks all!!!

Comment: src="{{file.content}}" won't work. But data-ng-src="{{file.content}}" should work

Comment: none of them are working. Check the second code piece. I'm showing both src and ng-src.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a directive that initializes the nivo slider for you. Something like:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('nivoSlider', function () {
  return {
    link: function ($scope, elem) {
      $scope.$apply(function () {
        $(elem).nivoSlider();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <nivo-slider id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img data-ng-repeat="file in files" data-ng-src="{{file.content}}" alt="" />
  </nivo-slider>
</div>
```

(not tested)